# function prints out a multiplication table

Tags: python, function

```
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in range(1, 2):
        for y in range(1, 3):
            print(str(X * y), end=" ")
        print()

multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

Should print the multiplication table shown below

Question

This function prints out a multiplication table (where each number is the result of multiplying the first number of its row by the number at the top of its column). Fill in the blanks so that calling `multiplication_table(1, 3)` will print out:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

Why is it not working

Answer (score 4):

```
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in range(start,stop+1):
        for y in range(start,stop+1):
            print(str(x*y), end=" ")
        print()

multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

As described by ypk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319424):

> ```
> def multiplication_table(start, stop):
>   for x in range(start,stop+1):
>       for y in range(start,stop+1):
>           print(str(x*y), end=" ")
>       print()
>
> multiplication_table(1, 3)
> ```

The start and stop variables should be used. Since we're using range function, we should use stop+1 to get the stop value involved.